# Recover an overwritten file

Tags: filesystem, data-recovery, tar

My project c source code file became corrupted while making the tgz of the file. I wanted to make *.tgz of 4 files. The file names are common.c, common.h, myfile.c and myfile.h. I mistyped the tar command. I used the following tar command by mistake

```
tar -cvf common.* myfile.* project.tgz
```

This has corrupted the common.c file. Is there any way to overcome this error. Kindly help me.

Thanks

Comment: You can try and look for a file called `common.c~` in the same folder as the original file. Some editors (like gedit) save backups here but that depends on the program.

Comment: Yeah. I tried. No swp files too :(.